# Finding the common elements between N lists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, intersection

I need to write a Java program that finds the intersection (common elements) of an arbitrary number of lists or arrays of integers (of arbitrary length). I guess that Java Lists may have a useful method in order to achieve this, but I am taking a look at the API and can´t find it.

Any hint?

Comment: You are looking for `retainAll`.

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki, can I ask you how would be the pseudo code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the common elements between two lists by copying the elements of one list into a new list, and using `retainAll`:

```
List<T> commonElements = new ArrayList<>(list1);
commonElements.retainAll(list2);
```

This can be extended to `n` lists, since the common elements in `n` lists are the common elements of [the common elements of the first `n-1` lists] and the [elements of the `n`-th list]:

```
commonElements.retainAll(list3);
commonElements.retainAll(list4);
...
```

e.g.

```
<T> List<T> commonElements(Iterable<? extends List<? extends T>> lists) {
  Iterator<? extends List<? extends T>> it = lists.iterator();
  List<T> commonElements = new ArrayList<T>(it.next());
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    commonElements.retainAll(it.next());
  }
  return commonElements;
}
```

Note that this will fail with a `NoSuchElementException` if lists is empty. It is straightforward to handle for this case, by adding a check for `it.hasNext()` before the first `it.next()`.

Comment: Thanks Andy, just a question, what is "T" in your method?

Comment: It's a type variable. Added.

Comment: `T` is a generic (arbitrary) type.

Comment: if `lists` is empty, it will fail with java.util.NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Indeed it will: I'd say that an exception should be used to indicate an undefined condition. You can trivially change it to return the empty list, however, if that is what is required. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `retainAll()` methods which is part of the Java `Collections` class:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(3);
System.out.println("First list has elements: " + list1);

List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(2);
list2.add(3);
list2.add(4);
System.out.println("Second list has elements: " + list2);

list1.retainAll(list2);
System.out.println("Intersection between the lists is: " + list1);
```

If you need to aggregate this for an arbitrary number of lists, you can simply call `list1.retainAll(listn)`, where `listn` is another `List`.

**Output:**

```
First list has elements: [1, 2, 3]
Second list has elements: [2, 3, 4]
Intersection between the lists is: [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should think *very* carefully before using any of the methods `retainAll`, `removeAll` or `containsAll` with `ArrayList`s because `contains` for an `ArrayList` has `O(n)` time complexity. If `a` and `b` are both `ArrayList`s of length `n`, `a.retainAll(b)` has time complexity `O(n^2)`. If you use `a.retainAll(b)` in a loop, the resulting algorithm quickly becomes completely impractical.

An alternative solution is to convert the `ArrayList`s to `HashSet`s. `contains` for a `HashSet` has `O(1)` time complexity.

```
static <T> List<T> commonElements(Iterable<? extends List<? extends T>> lists) {
    Iterator<? extends List<? extends T>> it = lists.iterator();
    Set<T> commonElements = new HashSet<>(it.next());
    while (it.hasNext())
        commonElements.retainAll(new HashSet<>(it.next()));
    return new ArrayList<>(commonElements);
}
```

Of course, if there are a small number of short `List`s, all the copying in the above code will make this version slower than @AndyTurner's. Which version you use depends on your exact situation.

Another problem with these solutions is how they deal with multiplicities. Suppose the first list is `[1, 1, 1]` and the second list is `[1, 1]`. The most reasonable interpretation for the intersection of these lists is `[1, 1]`. However, @AndyTurner's version will produce `[1, 1, 1]` and the above version will produce `[1]`.

Here is a version that deals with multiplicities correctly. Method references and `Map.merge` require Java 8.

```
static <T> List<T> commonElements(Iterable<? extends List<? extends T>> lists) {
    Iterator<? extends List<? extends T>> iterator = lists.iterator();
    Map<T, Integer> multiplicities = count(iterator.next());
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map<T, Integer> listCount = count(iterator.next());
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<T, Integer>> it = multiplicities.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry<T, Integer> e = it.next();
            T key = e.getKey();
            Integer count = listCount.get(key);
            if (count == null)
                it.remove();
            else
                e.setValue(Math.min(count, e.getValue()));
        }
    }
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<T, Integer> e : multiplicities.entrySet())
        result.addAll(Collections.nCopies(e.getValue(), e.getKey()));
    return result;
}

private static <T> Map<T, Integer> count(List<? extends T> list) {
    Map<T, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (T t : list)
        result.merge(t, 1, Integer::sum);
    return result;
}
```

You can test it as follows

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5);
List<Integer> common = commonElements(Arrays.asList(list1, list2));
System.out.println(common);
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

There are many ways to improve the above approach. For example, you could deal with the smallest `List` first to keep `multiplicities` as small as possible. Similarly, after computing `listCount`, you could swap `listCount` and `multiplicities` if `listCount` is smaller. Also you could replace the `while` by `while (!multiplicities.isEmpty() && iterator.hasNext())` so that the algorithm stops immediately as soon as the intersection is found to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this method to find intersection/common -

```
public <T> List<T> common(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        List<T> commonList = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (T t : list1) {
            if(list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }


        return commonList;
    }
```

Or you may use `retainAll()` methods -

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
```

Comment: This method take two lists, not an arbitary number of lists.