# How to create a list of objects that share common fields in nested lists (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, nested

Basically I am currently running into an issue as follows:

```
List<List<Person>> logLists;
```

I am given a list like above which is basically a list of logs, each log is a list of Person objects with certain fields. What I am trying to do is make a list of objects across every list in logLists that share the same value for a single field.

For example if each object is a person, like above, and a person class is defined as:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String socialSecurityNumber;

    public Person(String name, String socialSecurityNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
    }
    //implementation of methods...
}
```

Then how would I find the person objects whose social security numbers are common to ***ALL*** of the supplied logs (every list in the above nested list)?

```
String socialSecurityNumber;
```

Put another way, I want to find the person(s) that is/are in every log; the catch is that I can only go by social security number because some people in the logs could be under different names but still have the same SSN.

I just want to get an idea of how I can traverse this nested list and make a seperate list of the people who are in common to ***ALL*** of the log lists (in terms of the unique identifier: Social Security Number).

Pseudocode or just an explanation of how to approach this issue would be nice.

I have tried

```
Set.retainAll;
```

which is not useful because while it does automate things, it checks for object equivalence when I just want to see if a single field is equivalent.

Comment: well first thing I would do Is choose the biggest(longest) list in the collection and then you would have to do an iterative search of all the other arrays based on the social.  Make a class which has all the different fields in one and put a collection of that into another list for common people.  As all common people would have all available fields.

Comment: Note that `retainAll()` starts working when you define the `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) contracts (i.e. override these methods) of `Person` based on the `socialSecurityNumber` field.

Comment: im going to try altering my .equals method

Comment: That should work. You can then just iterate over the lists as shown here: [Finding the common elements between N lists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608680/finding-the-common-elements-between-n-lists-in-java).